# Using a Dirichlet distribution to estimate an expected response and uncertainity of response

Tags: variance, expected-value, dirichlet-distribution

I have an $N$ dimentional Dirichlet distribution $\text{Dir}\left(\alpha\right)$ that describes the number of times different responses, $r\in\left(1, 2, 3, \ldots N\right)=R$, have been observed. I am looking to make a prediction of what the next observed response will be, based only on the information in this distribution.

Can this be done with a weighted sum of the mean probabilities for each response?
$$\bar{r}=\sum_{r\in R}\frac{r\alpha_r}{\alpha_0}$$

With $\alpha_0=\sum_{r\in R}\alpha_r$

Can I make a useful estimate of the uncertainty of this estimate by summing the variances and covariances of the probability distributions for each response? If I understand correctly, this would be done with the variance defined for response $r$ as:
$$\text{Var}\left[\alpha_r\right]=\frac{\alpha_r\left(\alpha_0-\alpha_r\right)}{\alpha_0^2\left(\alpha_0+1\right)}$$
and the covariance between responses $r_1$ and $r_2$ as:
$$\text{Cov}\left[\alpha_{r_1},\alpha_{r_2}\right]=\frac{-\alpha_{r_1}\alpha_{r_2}}{\alpha_0^2\left(\alpha_0+1\right)}$$
Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure a Dirichlet distribution is the best (or even the correct) model for your problem. Correct me if I'm wrong but you seem to be describing $r$ as a discrete, univariate random variable and a Dirichlet describes a continuous, multivariate distribution over the $N$ dimensional simplex (e.g. a distribution over compositions). As such, multinomial would be a better model.

Comment: I actually meant categorical (a multinomial with sample size of 1).

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. It was suggested to me that I should use the Dirichlet distribution as it is the conjugate prior of the categorical and multinomial distributions.

Comment: That's true, but in those cases it serves as a prior on the probability vector $p$ that is then used to generate samples/counts for $r$. If you indeed want to use this prior, the best (in a theoretical sense) predictor would come from integrating over all $p$ vectors and all $r$ outputs simultaneously.

Comment: Integrating over $p$ gives a Dirichlet multinomial distribution: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet-multinomial_distribution.